# Tag for 'gender' request

Tags: support, tagging

I'd like to request a tag for gender, since it seems like there might be a lot of questions about navigating expectations around gender as people travel places with different cultures. Would've used it for [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107415/how-should-i-expect-a-non-gender-conforming-woman-to-be-received-in-india), and it would probably apply well to some related ones I saw also.

**Requested edit**

Questions this would fit for:

- [Non-gender conforming person in India](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107415/how-should-i-expect-a-non-gender-conforming-woman-to-be-received-in-india)
- [Women traveling in India](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12947/how-dangerous-is-india-for-solo-women-travellers-or-female-only-groups)
- [Men kissing each other's cheeks in Mongolia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22323/cheek-kissing-between-men-in-mongolia)
- [Men and women shaking hands in Mongolia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74192/is-it-ok-for-men-to-offer-to-shake-hands-with-women-in-mongolia)
- [Booking flights with a gender neutral passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79701/how-to-book-a-flight-if-my-passport-doesnt-state-my-gender)
- [Long-haired men and enforcing gender norms in North Korea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26667/is-it-safe-possible-for-a-long-haired-guy-to-visit-north-korea)

Comment: Searching for questions using the keyword "gender" returns [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=gender+is%3Aquestion).